# Expected Number of steps to reach 0.

Tags: probability, expected-value, dynamic-programming

Consider following problem,

You are given $N$ piles, $i^{th}$ pile has size $S_i$.

Until size of all the piles become $0$, repeat the following step.

With probability $p$, size of atmost one pile will be reduced by 1.

Goal is to find the expected number of steps. It is guranteed that $N \cdot p \leq 1$

I encountred the problem while thinking of some algorithmic problem. I would like to know there exist some solution other than bruteforce (using dynamic prgramming over all possible states). Only progress I was able to make is , If there are currently $K$ piles with size greater than 0, then there is $K\cdot p$ probability of moving one step closer to goal.

Comment: When you say "With probability p, size of atmost one pile will be reduced by 1", do you actually mean "With probability p, size of exactly one pile will be reduced by 1"?

Comment: Sorry I should have given some example. Consider 2 piles, with size $S_1,S_2$. With probability $P$ ,$S_1$ decreases by 1, With probability $P$ ,$S_2$ decreases by 1, and with probability $1-2P$, nothing happens. So that is like we have $N + 1$ events, where $N$ events will decrease size of some pile by 1, and for one event nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S=\sum S_i$. Let $P_k$ be the probability that the process ends at the $(S+k)$th step. (The minimum of number of steps is $S$.) The expected number of steps $E$ is:

$$E=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (S+k)P_k$$

$P_k$ is the product of the number of possibilities that the process ends at the $(S+k)$th step ($=A$) and the probability of each possibility ($=B$, which is a constant for fixed $k$).

$A$ would be the number of sequences that has $S+k$ elements and contains $S_i$ $i$'s and $k$ $0$'s. The $m$th element being $i$ means that the $i$th pile was reduced at the $m$th step; $0$ means no pile was reduced.

$$A= {S_1+\cdots+S_N +k \choose S_1}{S_2+\cdots+S_N+k \choose S_2}\cdots{S_N+k \choose S_N}{k \choose k} $$

$$A=\prod_{j=1}^N {\sum_{i=j}^N S_i \,+k \choose S_j}$$

$B$ would be the probability of reducing some specific pile $S$ times and doing nothing $k$ times.

$$B=p^S (1-pN)^k$$

In essence,

$$E=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \bigg[(S+k)p^S (1-pN)^k \prod_{j=1}^N {\sum_{i=j}^N S_i \,+k \choose S_j} \bigg]$$

Comment: Wouldn't the Value of N decreases with time?, I mean if a pile become empty, its Probability of reducing will be indirectly added to Probability of doing nothing. That is what I am trying to say is Probability of each Sequence A is not constant for fixed K.